# A template based Text Summarization using Python

Tags: python-3.x, text, nlp, topic-modeling, summarization

I want to extract key takeaways from a meeting transcript such as Project name , Challenges faced , Deadline , Solutions . I have a template for all these takeaways . 
So when after a meeting i need my model to extract text related to these takeaways.
Please give me some pointers regarding the problem and also I have a language constraint of using python.
Thanks

Comment: I am sorry, but your problem description is too vague/broad and touches too many topics, the like text-mining . Please rewrite your Question. Are you sure, that there are not enough examples on the web? Perhaps here you'll get some introduction for your attempt: http://stevenloria.com/finding-important-words-in-a-document-using-tf-idf/

Comment: Look into Named-Entity Recognition (NER)... Also a product called [Rambl](https://aftercode.io/).

Answer (score 0):

A naive way is to compare the meeting manuscripts to a list of takeaway keywords which are already stored in a list or dictionary, preferably with their semantics. This is a rule-based version. 
However, if you are trying to use machine learning, then you need to search in ieee, springer, or elsevier for similar works which might have addressed your problem or even some aspects of it.

I hope this helps.